# Set Binary Registry Key to GUID Value using Powershell or Powershell Desired State Configuration

Tags: powershell, binary, guid, dsc

We were instructed to update a REG_BINARY registry key using a GUID value, but we want to do this using PowerShell or PowerShell DSC so it can be automated. The end result should look like this:

[image: REG_BINARY key set to GUID value]

As that is the hex representation of the GUID:

```
GUID: {01234567-89AB-CDEF-0123-456789ABCDEF}
Hex:  67-45-23-01-AB-89-EF-CD-01-23-45-67-89-AB-CD-EF
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will create a new binary key using PowerShell

```
$value = [guid]::Parse('01234567-89AB-CDEF-0123-456789ABCDEF')
$path = 'HKLM:Software\Company\Product'
New-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name MyGUIDKey -PropertyType Binary -Value $value.ToByteArray()
```

If the key already exists you can update it's value by replacing the last line with

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name MyGUIDKey -Value $value.ToByteArray()
```

---

If you want to create or update they key using PowerShell DSC your configuration should look like:

```
Registry SetBinaryKeyToGuidValue
{
    Key = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Company\Product'
    ValueName = 'MyGUIDKey'
    ValueData =  @([BitConverter]::ToString([guid]::Parse('01234567-89AB-CDEF-0123-456789ABCDEF').ToByteArray()).Replace("-", [String]::Empty))
    ValueType = 'Binary'
}
```

The ValueData is very particular about what format is used, and it should be and Array of Hex strings like: @('001122FF'). If you use any other format you will get an error message like:

> PowerShell DSC resource MSFT_RegistryResource  failed to execute
>   Set-TargetResource functionality with error message: (ERROR) Parameter
>   'ValueData' has an invalid value
>   '01234567-89AB-CDEF-0123-456789ABCDEF' for type 'Binary'